# Android How can I pass GetText from onprexecute to do onBackground

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have 2 EditText fields which are email and name. When the user clicks a button I get the value of those 2 fields in the AsyncTask **onPreExecute()** method. My question is how can I now pass that value to the **doInBackground()** method and insert it into the String Answers ? I have learned that you should not pass  UI items into the **doInBackground()** . I have been searching on here and testing different variations of the code but keep getting Null values.

```
    private class myprofile extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean> {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            Email= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
            String email= Email.getText().toString();


            Name= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
            String name= Name.getText().toString();

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

            String email = params[0];
            String name = params[1];



            String Answers="email="+email+"&name="+name;

            return null;

        }

       // @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you pass your editText values to this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this. It looks like you're set up for passing them into `execute()`.

**1) Pass in to `AsyncTask.execute()`**

```
String email= Email.getText().toString();
String name= Name.getText().toString();
new myprofile().execute(email, name);
```

**2) Pass in to constructor**

```
private class myprofile extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {
    private String email;
    private String name;
    public myprofile(String email, String name){
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

```
String email= Email.getText().toString();
String name= Name.getText().toString();
new myprofile(email, name).execute();
```

**3) Retrieve in `onPreExecute()`**

```
private String email;
private String name;
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    email = Email.getText().toString();
    name = Name.getText().toString();
}
```